# How to import the package being frozen in the PyInstaller spec file?

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller, python-import

I have this directory structure:

```
mypackage/
|___ installer.spec
|___ package/
    |___ __init__.py
```

and `package.__init__.py` contains some variables I'd like to use in my `installer.spec` file.
So this file contains a `import package` line.
However, running `pyinstaller installer.spec` in mypackage/ fails with a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

How can I retrieve variables from the package I want to freeze while freezing it with PyInstaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spec file, change

```
import package

foobar = package.foobar
```

to

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    "package", "/full/path/to/package/__init__.py"
)
package = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(package)
foobar = package.foobar
```

Reference: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/5737038)